# Button Not Working in Tkinter Python Application

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib-basemap

I am writing a python application using tkinter that plots weather data on a map. I am currently testing out my button that is supposed to plot the data on the map I created using basemap. However, when I run my program, my button does nothing. I defined my function that plots the data and called the function in the command attribute of my button. Anyone know what the problem could be?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import requests

lon = [-76.5152, -76.7311, -76.3055, -76.7277, -75.4714, -75.1652, -77.0011, -75.6624, -78.3947, -77.8600, -78.7583, -79.9959, -80.0851]  
lat = [40.3295, 40.1998, 40.0379, 39.9626, 40.6023, 39.9526, 41.2412, 41.4090, 40.5187, 40.7934, 41.1210, 40.4406, 42.1292] 

def current_weather():
    key = '4a7a419e4e16e2629a4cedc37cbf7e50'
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    global observation
    observation = []
    for i in range(0,len(lon)):
       params = {'lat': lat[i], 'lon': lon[i], 'appid': key, 'units': 'imperial'}
       response = requests.get(url, params = params)
       weather = response.json()
       observation.append(round(weather['main']['temp']))
       
current_weather()

root = tk.Tk()

#place map on canvas
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-80.5, llcrnrlat=39.8, urcrnrlon=-74.7, urcrnrlat=42.3,resolution='i',
              lat_0 = 40., lon_0 = -80, ax = ax)
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#A6CAE0')
map.drawcounties(zorder = 20)
map.drawstates()
map.fillcontinents(color='#e6b800',lake_color='#A6CAE0')

def plot_data():
   for i in range(0, len(lon)):
      x,y = map(lon[i], lat[i])
      ax.text(x, y, observation[i], fontsize = 7)
      
#create widgets
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
radiovalue = tk.IntVar()
temperature = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Plot current temperatures", variable = radiovalue, value = 1)
dewpoint = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Plot current dewpoints", variable = radiovalue, value = 2)
wind = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Plot current winds", variable = radiovalue, value = 3)
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Plot", command = plot_data)

#organize widgets
temperature.place(relx = 0.025, rely = 0.8)
dewpoint.place(relx = 0.385, rely = 0.8)
wind.place(relx = 0.675, rely = 0.8)
button.place(relx = 0.35, rely = 0.1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? have you verified that `len(lon)` returns what you expect it to return? Inside the loop, are `x` and `y` set to what you think they should be set to?

Comment: I have verified that len(lon) and that x and y work the way they should. When I run the program without the plot_data() function, the data plots on the map the way it should. So, I only have an issue when I put the code that plots the actual data on the map inside of my plot_data() function. I'm guessing it has something to do with the scope of my variables, but I'm not sure what it is